# GUI for page change

Tags: python, arduino

Code function: When PYTHON reads the value 1 from the ARDUINO serial port, the GUI will proceed to the second page. If the value 5 is read, the GUI will return to the first page.

```
#THIS IS PAGE 1

def next1():
    win.destroy()
    import page2
        
while True:  
    while ser.in_waiting:
        date=list()
        date=ser.read()
        date=ser.read().decode()
        print(date)
        if(date=='1'):
            ser.close()
            next1()

#THIS IS PAGE 2

def cancel():
    ser.close()
    win2.destroy()
    import page1

while True:
    while ser.in_waiting:
        date=list()
        date=ser.read()
        date=ser.read().decode()
        print(date)
        if(date=='5'):
            cancel()
```

But when you go to the next page after returning to the first page, in `while ser_inwaiting` there will appear this error:

```
ClearCommError failed (OSError(9,'Control code is invalid.', None, 6))
```

How can you solve this?

Comment: You can't use nested imports like that.  An import only happens once, which is why they should always be at the top of the file.  page1.py needs a function that creates the first window.  page2.py needs a function that creates the second window.  You'll then have a `main.py` that imports both of them, and includes the functions to switch back and forth.'

Comment: im pretty sure ser is closed ... also ser.in_waiting is probably not really helping you... just `ser.read(1)` with a small timeout until you get your expected data ...

Comment: Can be said clearly I do not understand